# SQL Server OPENQUERY vs Regular Query against AS400

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, iseries

I log into a SQL Server database which has an AS400 server as a linked server.

I've discovered that running queries against this AS400 server is MUCH faster if I run the select in an OPENQUERY...

```
SELECT  EMEQP#
FROM _
WHERE EMALOC = '467' AND EMDLCD = 'A' AND EMSTAT NOT IN ('S', 'J', 'V')
```

Execution time: **46 seconds**

```
SELECT EMEQP#
FROM
OPENQUERY(_, '
SELECT  EMEQP#
FROM _
WHERE EMALOC = ''467'' AND EMDLCD = ''A'' AND EMSTAT NOT IN (''S'', ''J'', ''V'')
')
```

Execution time: **1 second**

Can someone explain or link me to why/how this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `openquery` the query itself executed on remote server and you receive only results. In case of linked server, you local server does all the job. You may want to check 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/transactsql/thread/0e68f512-1e19-4c50-b343-219085d70076

Comment: Glad to hear this is totally unrelated to `OPNQRYF`.